# ViewFlipper animation never ends?

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper setup where my setInAnimation() and setOutAnimation() are referring to classes that I've extended from Animation. This is all working fine, but what I have noticed is that after all the visual animation has finished ( ie. flip completed ) and whenever I click on the layouts inside my ViewFlipper area, I am still getting calls to my applyTransformation() in my animation classes with interpolatedTime = 1.

Does this mean the animation never ends properly ? I've tried to add an animation listener to my animation class and it is telling me that it ended. I am just wondering why it is calling applyTransformation() for no good reasons ( wasting CPU and battery ?? ), is there a way to stop this ? More importantly, I suspect this is the reason why I can getting a flicker whenever I touch the layout inside the ViewFlipper area. Any ideas ??

Thanks

Comment: Hey I'm facing a similar problem. Did you find any solution for it ?

Comment: solution never founded as well?